# Final Grades Program: how to convert number to letter for grades with method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that will:
Prompt the user for the number of grades that will be entered.
Take in the users name, and then their grade in two prompts.
Display their letter grade for each person.
Then calculate the class average, highest mark, and lowest mark from the input.

I need to have a method for the `convertGrade` (From number to letter).

Each method above should take in a list as a parameter.

The output can look something like this:

```
Welcome to the Final Grades Program

Enter the number of students: 3

Student's name: t
Student's mark (%): 32

Student's name: d
Student's mark (%): 78

Student's name: r
Student's mark (%): 89

t          F
d          B
r          A

Class Average:    67
Highest Mark:     89
Lowest Mark:      32
```

However, I can't work out how to convert number to letter for grades (because int and str don't work with > or <) So can I get some advice on what to do?

My mess of a code:

```
def intro():
    name = []
    mark = []

    while True:
        # Number of students
        numStudents = input("Enter the number of students: ")
        print ()

        #Info (Name/grade)
        for x in range(int(numStudents)):
            stuName = input("Student's name: ")
            stuMark = input("Student's mark (%): ")
            name.append(stuName)
            mark.append(stuMark)
                print ()

       if stuMark > 80:
                 print ("A")

            elif stuMark > 70 and stuMark < 79:
                 print ("B")

            elif stuMark > 60 and stuMark < 69:
                 print ("C")

            elif stuMark > 50 and stuMark < 59:
                 print ("D")
         
            elif stuMark < 50:
                 print ("F")

            else:
                 print ("Could not calculate grade.")
                 
# List
def list():
    print ()
    print("Student Name \t\t Student Grade")
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    for x in range(len(name)):
        print(f"{name[x]} \t\t\t {mark[x]}")

def main():
    print ("Welcome to the Final Grades Program")
    print()
    start = intro()
    show = list()

main()
```

Comment: While @Daniel Hao has provide you with a much more sophisticated  and elegant solution to your problem, simply replacing the ```stuMark``` in each of your conditionals with ```int(stuMark)``` witll give you the correct answer.  The reason you are getting the error is that input always returns a string type value.  To treat the value as a number, you need to convert the str variable to an int.

Comment: `list` is Python built-ins, so try to avoid using it for variable or function name. There are some errors that in your program, which I've tried to address in the post. Take a look and see if you can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mitzy, there are some nice function in Python for this quickly lookup - eg. `bisect()` module.  Try to get familiar with it.
So your program can be improved here:

```py
import bisect

def grading(score, points=[50, 60, 70, 80], grades='FDCBA'):
    i = bisect.bisect(points, score)
    #print(i)
    return grades[i]



def intro():
    students, marks = [], []

    while True:
        # Number of students
        numStudents = input("Enter the number of students: ")
        print ()

        #Info (Name/grade)
        for x in range(int(numStudents)):
            name = input("Student's name: ")
            mark = int(input("Student's mark (%): "))
            print(name, mark, grading(mark))
            
            students.append(name)
            marks.append(mark)
      

# List
def my_list():
    print ()
    print("Student Name \t\t Student Grade")
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    for x in range(len(name)):
        print(f"{name[x]} \t\t\t {mark[x]}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Welcome to the Final Grades Program")
    print()
    intro()
    my_list()
```

Outputs:

```
Welcome to the Final Grades Program

Enter the number of students: 3

Student's name: Alex
Student's mark (%): 91
Alex 91 A
Student's name: Bill
Student's mark (%): 82
Bill 82 A
Student's name: Cindy
Student's mark (%): 75

Cindy 75 B
Enter the number of students: 2
```